# Activex dll - new instance for http session

Tags: vb6, enterprise-library, com-interop

I have to build a vb.net mvc3 webinterface for our vb6 dms. My logic-tier is a multiuse active x dll and the user information is stored in a global. so whenever a new user logs on, the user information overrides the previous information.

is there a possibility to use a different component servers for each http-session?

Answer (score 0):

By using global variables you're implicitly asking for the data to be shared.

To have different data to different class instances, you will need to move the global data into a class, maybe with some form of session key so different requests get the correct instance back (if tier above doesn't already handle this)